# Is it possible to refer to a "real-time parent" function's variable from inside of a function of the same array?

Tags: javascript

I fully realize that this code is kinda strange by the very nature of javascript, but look at it:

```
var arr = [
    function () {
    this.b = "hello";
        //or var b = "hello";
        arr[1]();
    },
    function () {
        var str = RealtimeParentFunc.b;
        alert(str);
        // want to get "hello"
    }
];
// want to get "hello"!
arr[0]();
```

Maybe it's impossible, but I wonder if there's a way of doing this. How to get a variable of an array's function that called a function in the same array?

**UPDATE**
I had to go back to this problem and decided to post an update: of course I can't reference `arr[i]` from within itself, but I must emphasize that the code above was not supposed to be taken too literally: it was just a demo of what I wanted; but it looks like I can do what I want if I have a small "adjuvant" function that is previously defined in the code:

```
var a = function (i, v) {
        return arr[i]()[v];
    };
var arr = [
function () {
    var h = "hello, ";
    var n = a(2, "n");
    return {
        "h": h+n
    }
}, function () {
    var h = a(0, "h");
    alert(h)
}, function () {
    return {
        "n": "your name"
    }
}];
arr[1]();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define an array and access it's values at the same time, since at the time of creation, the `arr2` does not exist yet.

The `[ function(){ .. }, function(){ .. }]` array isn't created and set to `arr2` until it reaches the `;` semicolon at the end. Therefore you can't reference `arr2[1]()` while it's being defined.

On that note, what you can do is define the array first, then `.push()` the functions into it, but you're still limited to doing it sequentially:

```
var arr2 = [];

arr2.push(
function () {
    var b = "hello";
    //arr2[1](); // CAN'T DO THIS since arr2[1] doesn't exist
    return {
        b: b
    };
});
arr2.push(
function () {
    var str = arr2[0]().b;
    alert(str);
    // want to get "hello"
});
// want to get "hello"!
arr2[0]();
arr2[1]();
```

See working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/5k57X/